# why can't I call .update on a MessageDigest instance

Tags: java, clojure, hashcode

when i run this from the repl:

```
(def md (MessageDigest/getInstance "SHA-1"))
(. md update (into-array [(byte 1)  (byte 2)  (byte 3)]))
```

I get:

```
No matching method found: update for class java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate
```

the Java 6 docs for MessageDigest show:

```
update(byte[] input) 
      Updates the digest using the specified array of bytes.
```

and the class of `(class (into-array [(byte 1)  (byte 2)  (byte 3)]))` is
`[Ljava.lang.Byte;`

Am I missing something in the definition of update?
Not creating the class I think I am?
Not passing it the type I think I am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
(. md update (into-array Byte/TYPE [(byte 1) (byte 2) (byte 3)]))
```

Comment: Awsome! You got me unstuck! I do wonder why into-array didn't detect the type of the first entry?

Comment: Well I think @ZZCoder had that right below - it may have been detecting the Byte class rather than the primitive.

Comment: yes that would explain it. That lead me to test and fix this when hashing int vs. Integer also.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are calling update(Byte[]) which is not defined in MessageDigest. You need to convert it into primitive array.

You can do something like this,

```
 (defn updateBytes [#^MessageDigest md, #^bytes data] 
      (.update md data))
```

Comment: (. md update #^bytes (into-array [(byte 1)  (byte 2)  (byte 3)])) produces the same result. is "bytes" a name for the type-of-an-array-of-bytes?

Comment: #^bytes is a type hint, not an assertion or a cast or a declaration.  Hints only affect whether reflection is avoided when an object that matches the type hint is passed as the argument -- it does not yield an error when an object of an unrelated type is passed.